# Why is the none floated Bootstrap 4 container overlapping the floated container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why is the none floated Bootstrap 4 container overlapping the floated container? The boxes overlap but only mn of Column title 3 gets in the box of the floated columns.  I thought floated element are not touched by other elements.

```
  <div class="border border-danger container float-right ml-1 mb-1 mr-1  mt-null ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 float-right">
                <h3>Column title 1</h3> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 float-right">
                <h3>Column title 2</h3>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-danger container position-sticky">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 float-right"> 
                <h3>Column title 3</h3> 
                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share a code snippet with the issue? for me the divs do not overlap!

Comment: the floats aren't cleared and the next element has `position:sticky`.

Comment: still the same with position static and clerfix

Comment: Please send the screenshot and be specific with the css code also.

Comment: It's fixed,container is always max width of viewport.